# Revoking and requesting a new distribution certificate in apple dev center

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, developer-program, certificate

I'm trying update our iOS app through itunes connect. However, I'm having an issue with the iOS distribution certificate when I try to submit to the appstore.
This is the error that appears to me:

> Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate. You
>   have a valid iOS Distribution certificate in the Member Center, but it
>   is not installed locally. If your signing identity is installed on
>   another Mac, you can export a developer profile on that Mac and import
>   it on this Mac. You can also revoke your current certificate and
>   request a new one.

In the dev center, the distribution certificate and the adhoc profile appears to be invalid. So I'm wondering how to revoke and request a new certificate. If I revoked the certificate, what's going to happen? are there any additional fees?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem just today (Aug 13 2015)

Go into the member center, find the certificate, and revoke it.  Leave the member center.

xcode 6+ will automatically find the certicate has been revoked and will create & download a new one when you carry out an action that requires it.

I sometimes find it also helps to delete your account from Xcode->Preferences->accounts and add it back in.

Indeed it scared me the first time I tried it.